# Nagvis authentification with cURL

Tags: php, authentication, curl, nagios

I have a problem with NagVis authentication.
I have worked on 1.4.6 version and it worked. I passed on 1.7 version and impossible to have access at the map.

My php :

```
$url_map = "urlMap";
$ch = curl_init(urlMap."nameOfTheMap");

$password = "thePassword";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $_SESSION ['nagios_username'] . ':' .$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried to add :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

[image]
[image]

Now i arrived on authentication part, so the authentication doesn't worked and after I have error path.
I want arrive directly on the map.